# .htaccess regular expression issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, expression

I still have no answer about this so I'm posting it here.

I want to match an url in the form of `root/language/sub/.../document` in a .htaccess file and then rewrite it as `root/sub/.../document.php?lang=language`

Im close to hit but it seems my regexp doesn't 'catch' the input url. Here it is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^[a-z]{2}.*$/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $2.php?lang=$1
```

Can someone point me out what is wrong here ? I'm no expert in regexp nor apache rewrites.

Tyvm

*** EDIT ***

`root` stands for domain ie `mydomain.net`

Here are a few examples :

`mydomain.net/fr/contact`

should be rewriten to

`mydomain.net/contact.php?lang=fr`

and

`mydomain.net/en/articles/view`

should be rewriten

`mydomain.net/articles/view.php?lang=en`

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1%3.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ $1$3.php?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

***Explanation:***

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

*Checks if requested url is not a directory. If yes, no rewriting will be processed.*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ [NC]
```

*Checks if url contains `/xx/` part inside, where `xx` is one `en`, `de` or `fr`. Flag `[NC]` allows uppercase and lowercase charactes, so for example `EN` or `Fr` will be accepted. If there is no such "language" part in the url, no rewriting will be processed.*

```
RewriteCond %1%3.php -f
```

*Checks if `%1%3.php` file exists, where `%1` is `(.*/|)` and `%3` is `(.*)` matches from the previous RewriteCond `^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)/(.*)$`. If such php file does not exist, no rewriting will be processed.*

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ $1$3.php?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

*In the RewriteRule left condition will be matched if it came to this line, as it was already checked with RewriteCond, so now it will process rewriting to php file, adding **lang** part, but because there is also `[QSA]` flag, it will keep also other GET parameters, so **lang** will be added to existing parameters. Flag `[L]` says it is last rewriting rule that should apply and no more rewriting will be processed with this url.*

Comment: TYVM. Can't check it right now but will definitely tomorrow and keep you informed. Now I still have a last question. If I add some other GET variables, they should be added to the `lang=foo` parameter. So it looks to my like => search for `\?.*` at the end of string if so add `&lang=foo` else add `?lang=foo`. This way I don't lose GET behaviours. I think you can add a `RewriteRule` line with that before yours ? Or do I need to make another block of `RewriteCond` for each `RewriteRule` ? Thanks, I pop your as accepted answer ^^

Comment: (Just for some clarity points) Does `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` contain the full URI ie `mydomain.net/fr/contact` ? If not then `(.*/|)` (second line) makes no sense to me as the lang would then be the first url _bit_. As well, what is the pipe `|` for in `(.*/|)` ? I understand `(.*/)` matches everything ending with a `/`. Wild guess : optional condition ? Thanks for help any case.

Comment: @JulienMatthey - Flag `[QSA]` will take care of `?`/`&` issue automatically, don't worry about that :) Regarding your question about `(.*/|)` - this will match anything ending with `/` prior language abbreviation, or empty string is there is nothing there, so `|` is **or** operator here. I hope this helps.

Comment: Made a final edit. The solution pretty much works for me now except some little things.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what root is doing in there, have you tried

```
RewriteRule ^root/([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ root/$2.php?lang=$1
```

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer, `root` actually stands for `domain` (i.e. `mydomain.net`)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is the second `RewriteCond`.  But your question is vague.  If you mean you're trying to convert

```
root/foo/sub/.../something.php
```

to

```
root/sub/.../something.php?lang=foo
```

then start fidgeting with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^root/([^/]+)/sub/(.*)/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}$ root/sub/$2/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}?lang=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - testing it right now. I just made an edit so please read. `root` actually stands for domain ie `mydomain.net`. Sorry to have confused you guys here ^^