# .htaccess RewriteCond small issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

thanks to @Ωmega, I almost completely resolved my former issue (details here [.htaccess regular expression issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327059/htaccess-regular-expression-issue)) and came to this solution :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1%3index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/|)$ index.php?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*|)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond $1$3.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*|)$ $1$3.php?lang=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Basically, these lines will rewrite anything in the form of `domain/language/sub/.../somepage` to `domain/sub/.../somepage.php?lang=language`. The first block is for urls in the form of `domain/language/`, with or without an ending `/` which is redirected to `index.php`.

This works very well tho two small glitches remain which are :

1. The 3rd line in the second block (I #commented it) just doesn't match, no matter what. The strange part is that it DOES work on the 4th line, ie my page actually displays fine. Does that mean the `-f` parameter is wrong here ?
2. If I input any url ending with a `/` (second block only, it DOES work with the index file), my rewrite is broken ie outputs as `domain/language/sub/.../somepage/.php` Is there any way to exclude a potential `/` in the inputed url with the regexp ?

Thank you for your feedback !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 3rd line in the second block (I #commented it) just doesn't match, no matter what. The strange part is that it DOES work on the 4th line, ie my page actually displays fine. Does that mean the -f parameter is wrong here ?

You are using the wrong backreferences. You want %1 and %3:

```
RewriteCond %1%3.php -f
```

> If I input any url ending with a / (second block only, it DOES work with the index file), my rewrite is broken ie outputs as domain/language/sub/.../somepage/.php Is there any way to exclude a potential / in the inputed url with the regexp ?

Yes, you can try changing your regexp from `^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*|)$` to `^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*?)/?$` in both the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.

Comment: This `^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*?)/?$` doesn't match at all. This `^(.*/|)(en|de|fr)(/.*|)/?$` eventually matches but the problem is the same, the ending `/` is eaten up by the third `()` group and ends up outputing `somepage/.php`. Now for the RewriteCond, it doesn't work :( but really don't know why. Even if my page displays correctly and after that I uncomment `#RewriteCond %1%3.php -f`, the url doesn't match anymore. Weird.

Comment: The `?` inside the parens makes it a non-greedy search, so that the last `/?` isn't gobbled up by the `.*` grouping

Comment: Okay this works, but you forgot to mention to make the modification only on the `RewriteRule` line. Thanks